# Why does django not see my tests?

Tags: python, django, testing, client

I've created test.py module, filled with

```
from django.test import TestCase
from django.test.client import Client
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.sites.models import Site

from forum.models import *

class SimpleTest(TestCase):


    def setUp(self):
        u = User.objects.create_user("ak", "ak@abc.org", "pwd")
        Forum.objects.create(title="forum")
        Site.objects.create(domain="test.org", name="test.org")

    def content_test(self, url, values):
        """Get content of url and test that each of items in `values` list is present."""
        r = self.c.get(url)
        self.assertEquals(r.status_code, 200)
        for v in values:
            self.assertTrue(v in r.content)

    def test(self):
        self.c = Client()
        self.c.login(username="ak", password="pwd")

        self.content_test("/forum/", ['<a href="/forum/forum/1/">forum</a>'])
        ....
```

and placed it in folder with my application.
When i run tests by

```
python manage.py test forum
```

after creating the test database i get an answer  "Ran 0 tests in 0.000s"

What am i doing wrong ?

P.S.
Here is my project hierarchy:

```
MyProj:
    forum (it's my app):
        manage.py
        models.py
        views.py
        tests.py
        ...
```

I renamed test.py to tests.py. Eclipse got that this module is with tests, but answer is still "Ran 0 tests in 0.000s"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is something not quite right if you are getting the same result after renaming the file to `tests.py`. How are you running the tests? Are you doing so from the command line or have you set up a custom run target using Eclipse? Please try it from the command line if you haven't already.

Also fire up Django shell (`python manage.py shell`) and import your tests module.

```
from MyProj.forum.tests import SimpleTest
```

Does the import work correctly?

Comment: I tryed "python manage.py shell" and "from MyProj.forum.tests import Test_forum" (i renamed test class), and it didn't work. But "import MyProj.forum.tests" and "from MyProj.forum.tests import *" passed without errors.

Comment: Looks like something is amiss. Try this: `from MyProj.forum import tests` followed by `dir(tests)`. See if your class name is present in the output of the `dir` command.

Comment: As it was expected: <code> >>> dir(tests)
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__'] </code> 
So, there is no my test class in tests.py.
What did i missed ?

Comment: This is interesting: there is no `Test_forum` in that list. It seems to me that you have a directory named `tests` in there. This would explain why `from MyProj.forum.tests import Test_forum` fails but `import MyProj.forum.tests` succeeds. Can you check if this is the case?

Comment: Yes, you were right. I tryed to test my app with nose and urllib/urllib2 first, and for this purpose i've created package tests.  I removed this package and django test tool got my test class in tests.py. Thank you, Manoj Govindan. You saved me !

Answer (score 41):

You´ll need to use the prefix `test_` for each test method.

Comment: Me too, on Django 1.4. Thx!

Answer (score 21):

**Summary**

0. Try running for your app only:

   ```
   python manage.py test YOUR_APP
   ```
1. Check in your `settings.py` file if YOUR_APP is in `INSTALLED_APPS` config.
2. Test method should start with `test_`, e.g.:

   ```
   def test_something(self):
       self.assertEquals(1, 2)
   ```
3. If you are using a directory called `tests` instead of the `tests.py` file, check if it has a `__init__.py` file inside it.
4. If you are using a `tests` directory, remove `tests.pyc` and `tests.pyo` files. (`__pycache__` dir for Python3)

Comment: In addition to 4, don't forget to remove the `__pycache__` folder

Comment: My Problem was 2. Thanks.

Comment: FYI: Updated formatting. The underscores in filenames were rendered as bold in Markdown without backticks (codeblocks).

Answer (score 7):

Try renaming your method `test` to something like `test_content`.

I believe the test runner will run all methods named `test_*` (see the python docs for [organising test code](http://docs.python.org/library/unittest.html#organizing-test-code). Django's `TestCase` is a subclass of `unittest.TestCase`, so the same rules should apply.

Comment: I have renamed my test class to Test_forum. But it didn't help

Comment: Don't rename the class, rename the method. It might be case sensitive so try test_forum.

Answer (score 5):

You have to name it `tests.py` .

Comment: I renamed test.py to tests.py. Eclipse got that this module is with tests, but answer is still "Ran 0 tests in 0.000s"

Answer (score 4):

After some time spent in searching I did not find anyone suggesting this, so I will share it as a late answer.
In my case I have my `manage.py` in the root directory eg

```
.
...
├── dir
│   ├── project_name
│   ├── manage.py
│   ├── media
│   ├── app1
│   ├── static
│   ├── staticfiles
│   ├── templates
│   └── app2
...
```

so I found that [the test command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-test) has the option to provide project which tests' to run. In my case I had to do this

```
python project_name/manage.py test ./project_name/
```

This successfully ran my tests.

Answer (score 3):

I had tried all these things but I neglected to add the __init__.py file in the tests directory that I created to hold all my tests and Django couldn't find it.